# Fourier Transformation: an Animated GIF

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

[Here](http://en.docsity.com/news/education-2/math-gifs-learning/) I found the animated GIF below. I don't get it! Would someone explain it please?
[image]

Comment: You should wait a couple days before crossposting.  This is not appropriate for MathOverflow.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Thanks for your advice. I deleted the other post.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function. It is like a box! Or maybe a skyscraper.

You want to approximate such a function, but all you have is a bag of sinusoids of different frequencies. Perhaps, if you add these sinusoids together, you can approximate the function.

You reach into your bag, and pull out of a bunch of sinusoids and add them all together. If you pick the right amplitude for each one, you get something that looks like your original function!

Now, you ask yourself, "what if I arranged these sinusoids that I used by increasing frequency, and plotted the amplitude of each one? What would it look like?"

Now you have a Fourier transform!

Comment: Crucially, instead of a finite, or discrete number of sinusoids, you have one for each and every frequency.  Instead of summing them up, you integrate them!

Comment: @Arkamis Thanks. What is the final function $\hat f(\xi)$? How is its graph generated, using the graphs of the blue (trigonometric) functions?

Comment: @Behzad The blue function represents the amplitude of each sinusoid at each frequency. The horizontal axis represents frequency, and the vertical axis represents amplitude. This is known as the "frequency domain" or "Fourier domain."